# Zeppelin Error: "Interpreter process is not running" after delploy to Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, apache-zeppelin

I am new to these docker, kubernetes and zeppelin.
Currently I deploy one docker image to kubernetes cluster, and when I try to run a very simple python code, it give the following error, I checked the interpreter, they are all green, any one has idea what's the possible reason? thank you, also attached the yaml file I am using

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Interpreter process is not running
null
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:134)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:298)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:431)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:74)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:130)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Interpreter process is not running
null
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:166)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:131)
    ... 13 more
```

Yaml File:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zeppelin-spark
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zeppelin-spark
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zeppelin-spark
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zeppelin-spark
        image: 411028718373.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zeppelin:official
        command: [ "/bin/bash", "-ce", "tail -f /dev/null" ]
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "4Gi"
          requests:
            memory: "2Gi"
        # volumeMounts:
        # - mountPath: "/media"
        #   name: test-volume
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      # volumes:
      # - name: test-volume
      #   persistentVolumeClaim:
      #     claimName: test-volume
```

Comment: Did you solve it??

Answer (score 4):

Go to the zeppeline web ui and click the settings icon in the top right corner, then choose the proper interpreter and drag it to the top position in the "Interpreter binding" zone, save it and try again running the paragraph.